# Where is the V8 Engine JS Operator Source Code?

Tags: javascript, v8

Where are the basic operators (+, >, <, etc.) defined in the source code? I think the Chrome Engine is called V8? But I don't feel like downloading, compiling and debugging it to find out.

I looked in some the .h/.cc files, gave up and came here.

Comment: Just curious as to why you need this? Do you want to change the behavior of the basic operators?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169451/where-is-the-v8-engine-js-operator-source-code#comment134326485_76169451) @ThomasFrank I can't speak for OP, but the best way to determine enumerations is to go to the source: in this case, to know with certainty which operators are available in V8.

Comment: Makes sense - if you are into deep diving :)

Answer (score 2):

(V8 developer here.)

There isn't just one "definition" of an operator.

There are [token definitions](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/parsing/token.h;l=33?q=BINARY_OP_TOKEN_LIST&sq=) in the tokenizer.
There are [AST node definitions](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/ast/ast.h;l=1860?q=v8::internal::BinaryOperation) in the parser.
There are [bytecode handler implementations](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/interpreter/interpreter-generator.cc;l=905?q=Generate_AddWithFeedback) in the interpreter, which are reusing code that's also used to [generate](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/ic/binary-op-assembler.cc;l=22?q=BinaryOpAssembler::Generate_AddWithFeedback&sq=) stand-alone builtin stubs, and there's the corresponding code in the [bytecode generator](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/interpreter/bytecode-generator.cc;l=6546?q=BytecodeGenerator::VisitBinaryOperation&sq=).
And then [each](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/baseline/baseline-compiler.cc;l=961?q=BaselineCompiler::VisitAdd) [of](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/maglev/maglev-graph-builder.cc;l=1535?q=MaglevGraphBuilder::VisitBinaryOperation&sq=) [the](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/compiler/bytecode-graph-builder.cc;l=2911?q=BytecodeGraphBuilder::BuildBinaryOp) compilers has its own handling of them with varying levels of optimization; especially in case of the optimizing compiler there's also a [bunch](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/compiler/js-typed-lowering.cc;l=354?q=NumberOp&sq=) [of](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/compiler/js-typed-lowering.cc;l=551?q=JSTypedLowering::ReduceJSAdd) [further](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/compiler/js-type-hint-lowering.cc;l=142?q=SpeculativeNumberOp&sq=) [processing](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/compiler/representation-change.cc;l=1305?q=RepresentationChanger::Int32OperatorFor) of the operators in its various stages.

If you're trying to understand which operators are available, as one commenter is speculating, it's probably easier to look at the [JavaScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-unary-operators) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Answer (score 1):

The definition of operators seems to be located here:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/1769f892cef0822e6a8b5334e2ad909a0c33e906/src/compiler/js-operator.h

Answer (score 0):

Where did you check the source code of V8 engine?
I can see many operators defined and used in the source.
Please check the following link.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/builtins/builtins-number.cc
Regards